# While submitting a form in react hooks form to send an email, I am getting below CORS error Access-Control-Allow-Origin even after passing it

Tags: reactjs, express, cors

While submitting a form in react hooks form to send an email, I am getting below CORS error.
I have already defined `corsOptions` and passing that to app.use(cors())
Could someone please advise how can I fix the issue ?
//error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com.au/service/emailtransfer' from origin 'https://example.com.au' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

// server.js:

```
const app = express();
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://example.com.au',
  methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS',
  allowedHeaders: 'Authorization, Content-Type',
  credentials: true,
  exposedHeaders: 'Content-Length',
  maxAge: 3600
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions)) // Use this after the variable declaration

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/service/emailtransfer', async (req, res) => {

  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://example.com.au');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Athorization, Content-Type');
  res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Length');
  res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');

  const senderEmail = req.body.email;
  const senderMobile = req.body.mobile;
  const senderComments = req.body.comments;
  console.log("Contact details in server side:: "+senderEmail, senderMobile, senderComments );

  

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    
    host: "smtpout.secureserver.net", //smtp.office365.com
    secure:true,
    secureConnection: false,
    tls: {
      ciphers:'SSLv3'
    },
    requireTLS: true,
    port:465, 
    debug:true,
    auth: {
      user: godaddyUserEmail, // Replace with your godaddy email
      pass: godaddyEmailPassword, // Replace with your godaddy email password
    },
  });


  try {
    await transporter.sendMail({
      from: senderEmail, // Replace with your email
      to: recipientJegniLifeEmail, // Replace with the recipient's email
      subject: 'Enquiry request from Example website',
      text: `SendersEmail: ${senderEmail}\nMobile Number: ${senderMobile}\nComments: ${senderComments}`,
    });
    res.status(200).json({ success: true });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.status(500).json({ message: e.message });
  }
});
```

Comment: Check if you are sending request body with correct format to match with backend api if you are confidence your cors setting is correct.

Comment: Yes, the same code was working fine with http:// . But after adding ssl to site and made necessary nginx configuration have started getting this error

Comment: Instead of app.post() , does it need to change to app.use() ?

Comment: If you have any clue, please advise. I will try that

Comment: The error message indicates that this is a same-origin request (that doesn't involve Private Network Access). Such a request doesn't require CORS. There must be something you're not telling us. Closing as "cannot be reproduced".

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, it seems you need to config your ssl cert before start running the app. so add this config to app.js file

```
const https = require("https");
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
// start the Express server
httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port: ${PORT}`);
});

try {
  const httpsServer = https.createServer(
    {
      key: fs.readFileSync(
        "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com.au/privkey.pem" // Change with your path which located ssl files
      ),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(
        "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com.au/fullchain.pem" // Change with your path as well
      ),
    },
  app
 );

 httpsServer.listen(SECURE_PORT, () => {
   console.log(`Secure server is running on port: ${SECURE_PORT}`);
 });
} catch (e) {
  console.log("error", e);
}
```